# add item to the settings in android framework

Tags: android, frameworks

i am working in android frameworks.i want to add an item to the existing settings in the android OS.can u plz tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read about [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html). These group of classes handle user prefs.

Then depending on your task, do something like [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/111f6d02533f0492#).

In case you want to add a live wallpaper or an input method add `android:settingsActivity` in your Manifest. (Example : [here](http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/source/browse/trunk/project/res/xml/method.xml))

Or follow [this tutorial](http://jmdonovan.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/android-%E2%80%93-with-eclipse-v3-5-ide-app%E2%80%99s-menu-adding-a-%E2%80%9Cmenu%E2%80%9D-at-the-bottom-of-the-app-screen/)

Comment: What is this or this?