# How to add App Settings(Prefrences) in Android default Settings?

Tags: android, settings, default

I am making developing an app and I'm using res/xml/settings.xml for my preferences.

It works fine But now I want these settings to be in the Android Default settings.

I 've searched a lot but couldn't find a solution.

Can anybody help me how to add app settings in the android Default settings(Wireless and networks,Call Settins,Sound,Applications etc.. ).

Thanks in advance....

Comment: What you mean Android Default settings?

Comment: means where all the settings are there like Wireless and networks,Call Settins,Sound,Applications etc..

Comment: see these links might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524110/how-to-add-preference-of-custom-input-method-to-android-settings-app/3528859#3528859   and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259637/add-item-to-the-settings-in-android-framework

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096555/how-to-add-own-setting-to-system-settings

Answer (score 0):

You can't add your own application settings to the Default Android Settings application.

They should live inside your application. If you want the same look and feel as the default settings you should use a [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) or [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) for Honeycomb+

Comment: But i had  explained in my question that i had already used PreferenceActivity in my app.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact you can't put your settings into the already existing settings application.